# Close python script and reopen it

Tags: python

i have a python script that i want to close console and then execute again the script from the beginning. Can you help me with this?

I need to close it when i execute a function on the script. Then reopen the file so it's ready again for doing something.

Comment: what have you tried? Also, what exactly are you trying to do? You want a script that closes itself then runs itself again when it is closed? I don't know if that's possible - you'd probably need a script (A) that calls another script (B, which does what you want) and then calls it (B) again

Comment: @IanQuah Ok nice i got a server.py file that runs an api server. Then if i send some data i will run an specific function, at the final of that specific function i need to close my server and executing it again for listening.

Comment: @IanQuah i think i will need a script that will call the server file. And then when the server file executes the function if will close the process and then reopen it. But i dont know how i can do that

Comment: Can I ask the reason the script needs to close? Could you just not keep it open to handle the next request? This would be a great case for python flask. Just create a server, when it gets data it can call a function. It will just keep on listening.

Comment: @mikeg I got a selenium script on python that would do some tasks. So i defined some vars so it can handle the steps that will need to do, one by one. Because it will need to request another data to the client. So i have 2 api functions. I think the problem i got is when i want to reset the vars on the step. Let me analyze better my script and i will text here

Answer (score 2):

You should import your script instead. You can import python files from same directory. An example:

rerun.py:

```
def print_stuff():
    print('stuff')
```

runner.py:

```
from rerun import print_stuff

print_stuff()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flask. It is made for this. Go take a look at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def some_function():
    print('do stuff here')
```